# Why My Camera preview shows Horizontal instead of the Vertical?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-camera

In My Android Camera Application if i fix the Screen to the landscape then In landscape mode it seems as it have to be seen. but if i fix it to the portrait then the Camera preview is seen to the horizontal.
Why it is Happening ? and Whats the Sollution for it ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
 parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
 mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
```

You can call startPreview() after this :)

Comment: I have Check it. But still problem is there. What should i have to do ?

Comment: If i have fix the My Application Manifest to portrait and if i face Android Device as Portrait then it display the preview in Landscape and if i put android device as Landscape then it will display preview in portrait.   If i have set the Manifest to the Landscape then all works fine. But as per need i want camera to set in Portrait mode.