# Why does my Android Camera Preview show landscape even if I have set Application Manifest to the Portrait?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-camera

In My Android camera application, I have set my Application manifest to the Portrait. But while I am running am running my camera application, the camera preview is shown as landscape instead of the portrait.

I don't know where the problem is, but I need help for it.
I want to Set My Camera Preview as Shown like Normal camera Preview. And set application to portrait.

Any solution for it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why My Camera preview shows Horizontal instead of the Vertical?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885873/why-my-camera-preview-shows-horizontal-instead-of-the-vertical)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);` should do the trick so long as it stays portrait.

Also, per documentation:

```
public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
         int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
   android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
   android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
   int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
   int degrees = 0;
   switch (rotation) {
         case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
   }

   int result;
   if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
       result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
       result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
   } else {  // back-facing
       result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
   }
   camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
}
```

This code segment can be applied to set the orientation of the camera based on the orientation of the phone.

Comment: ... and do not forget cave ats with previoew image orientation

Comment: CaveAt means that regardles of your camera orienttion settings,  preview pixels are delivered in  camera chip readout order ( typically top right corner of display)

Comment: ok. Thnks. All Works nice. But while i am captured image then the Image is display in to Landscape mode instead of the Portrait. Then what should i have to do ?

Comment: @DeeV: Your Code works fine. but i have little issue in it. While i am going to captured the image it is saved in to Landscape mode instead of the portrait mode. Why it is like that ??